# How to put a SQL ResultSet into an Array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc

I am working on a project with JDBC.  I wanted to select the username out of a database(called profil) that contains usernames and passwords. I wanted to save the usernames one by one in the array Kontakte2.
Can someone maybe help me?

```
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();   
    String q = "select username from profil";
    ResultSet username = stmt.executeQuery(q);
    String[] Kontakte2 = new String[100];

    int i = 0;
    while(username.next()){
        Kontakte2[i] =  username.getString(1);
        i++;
    }


} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Aren't you ding the same thing now? What issue are you facing?

Comment: I get a java.lang.NullPointerException :/

Comment: Well, that means you are dereferencing a null value. As you don't show the stacktrace, we can't help you. Use your debugger and check what is null at the point the NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: Welcome to StackOvverflow! This site has some rules in order to help providing an interesting set of Q&A for future readers references. In particular, you are supposed to give all information that could help to narrow the problem: the exact error message, the stack trace and the line where the error occurs. You should read [ask]...